# Proper way of creating continuously self-restarting NodeJS script?

Tags: node.js

I'm running a nodeJS script that is supposed to stay up forever. However, one of its components can crash uncontrollably and the whole thing needs to be restarted.

1. Is there any difference in terms of memory usage or performance of any kind between the options I've listed below?
2. What is the proper way to profile memory and CPU usage in NodeJS?

```
// option #1
const start = async () => {
  // do async stuff
  await start()
}
start()

// option #2
const start = async () => {
  // do async stuff
  start()
}
start()

// option #3
async function start (argument) {
  // do async stuff
  start()
}
start()

// option #4
async function start (argument) {
  // do async stuff
  await start()
}
start()
```

p.s. I'm using `try...catch...finally` to catch the crash and restart but it seems not related to the matter of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package to run forever:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever
```

Comment: I know of this package and other analogs. Though it's not what I need. I don't want to restart the whole script.